# how to stack LSTM layers using TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

what I have is the following, which I believe is a network with one hidden LSTM layer:

```
# Parameters
learning rate = 0.001
training_iters = 100000
batch_size = 128
display_step = 10

# Network Parameters
n_input = 13
n_steps = 10
n_hidden = 512
n_classes = 13

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_steps, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

# Define weights
weights = {
    'out' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'out' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}
```

However, I am trying to build an LSTM network using TensorFlow to predict power consumption.  I have been looking around to find a good example, but I could not find any model with 2 hidden LSTM layers. Here's the model that I would like to build:

1 input layer, 
1 output layer, 
2 hidden LSTM layers(with 512 neurons in each), 
time step(sequence length): 10

Could anyone guide me to build this using TensorFlow? ( from defining weights, building input shape, training, predicting, use of optimizer or cost function, etc), any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I do it in a translation model with GRU cells.  You can just replace the GRU with an LSTM.  It is really easy just use tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell with a list of the multiple cells it should wrap.  In the code bellow I am manually unrolling it but you can pass it to `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` or `tf.nn.rnn` as well.

```
y = input_tensor
with tf.variable_scope('encoder') as scope:
    rnn_cell = rnn.MultiRNNCell([rnn.GRUCell(1024) for _ in range(3)])
    state = tf.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, rnn_cell.state_size))
    output = [None] * TIME_STEPS
    for t in reversed(range(TIME_STEPS)):
        y_t = tf.reshape(y[:, t, :], (BATCH_SIZE, -1))
        output[t], state = rnn_cell(y_t, state)
        scope.reuse_variables()
    y = tf.pack(output, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Do I still need to initialize variables(parameters) from hidden layer1 to hidden layer2 or are they internally taken care of?

Comment: The variables for the LSTM get initialized when you use it inside of the class.  Take a look at the source code it is pretty helpful.

Comment: I see that the variables for the four gates of LSTM get initialized, but shouldn't there also be parameters from the first hidden layer to the second? It would make sense if MultiRNNCell initializes parameters from one hidden to another.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  It creates all the variables you need.

Answer (score 2):

First you need some placeholders to put your training data (one batch)

```
x_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, truncated_series_length, 1])
y_output = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, truncated_series_length, 1])
```

A LSTM need a state, which consists of two components, the hidden state and the cell state, very good guide here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.00019.pdf. For every layer in the LSTM you have one cell state and one hidden state.

The problem is that Tensorflow stores this in a LSTMStateTuple which you can not send into placeholder. So you need to store it in a Tensor, and then unpack it into a tuple:

```
state_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [num_layers, 2, batch_size, state_size])

l = tf.unpack(state_placeholder, axis=0)
rnn_tuple_state = tuple(
    [tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(l[idx][0], l[idx][1])
     for idx in range(num_layers)]
)
```

Then you can use the built-in Tensorflow API to create the stacked LSTM layer.

```
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(state_size, state_is_tuple=True)
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell]*num_layers, state_is_tuple=True)
outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x_input, initial_state=rnn_tuple_state)
```

From here you continue with the outputs to calculate logits and then a loss with respect to the `y_inputs`.

Then you run each batch with the `sess.run`-command, with truncated backpropagation (good explanation here http://r2rt.com/styles-of-truncated-backpropagation.html)

```
 init_state = np.zeros((num_layers, 2, batch_size, state_size))

...current_state... = sess.run([...state...], feed_dict={x_input:batch_in, state_placeholder:current_state ...})
current_state = np.array(current_state)
```

You will have to convert the state to a `numpy` array before feeding it again.

Perhaps it is better to use a librarly like Tflearn or Keras instead?

Comment: Didn't want to edit since it depends on the tensorflow Version you're using: But it seems that tf.unpack has changed to tf.unstack